# Unspecified launch failure after cudaDeviceSynchronize() call when program starts. But no errors using step-through debugging. CUDA

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-debugging

I've spent several hours struggling with `unspecified launch failure`.
I've come up with a tiny task for myself in order to understand how shared memory works.

Task is to divide array [1, 2, 3, ... , N] into K group of (N / K) elements and find the sum of each group. (Difference between current and previous element of the array equals 1)

I was planning to use N threads in grid divided between K blocks. So every threadblock contains (N / K) threads. Thus one threadblock could be used to compute sum of one group. Also I wanted to dynamically allocate shared memory.

When I start program I got `unspecified launch failure` after `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` call. But when I try step-through debugging everthing is ok and works fine.

What am I doing wrong? (Visual Studio 2012 Professional, Compute Capability 2.1) I would very appreciate any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#define CUDA_CALL(x) do { if((x) != cudaSuccess) { \
    printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__); \
    printf("%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(x)); \
    system("pause"); \
    return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0)

extern __shared__ double shrd[];

__global__ void kernel(double * a){
    size_t threadID_block = blockDim.x * threadIdx.y + threadIdx.x;
    size_t blockID_global = (gridDim.x * blockIdx.y + blockIdx.x );
    size_t threadID_global = blockID_global * blockDim.x * blockDim.y + threadID_block;
    double * temp = &shrd[blockID_global * blockDim.x * blockDim.y];
    temp[threadID_block] = static_cast<double>(threadID_global);

    __syncthreads();
    if (threadID_block == 0){
        a[blockID_global] = 0.0;
        for (size_t index = 0; index < blockDim.x * blockDim.y; index++){
            a[blockID_global] += temp[index];
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    int devNum = 0;
    CUDA_CALL(cudaGetDevice(&devNum));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaSetDevice(devNum));


    dim3 gridSize(2,2,1);
    dim3 blockSize(4,4,1);

    double * dev_a = NULL;
    size_t length = gridSize.x * gridSize.y ;
    size_t byteSize = length * sizeof(double);
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc(&dev_a,byteSize));

    size_t shmem_perBlock = blockSize.x * blockSize.y * sizeof(double);
    kernel <<< gridSize, blockSize,  shmem_perBlock >>> (dev_a);
    CUDA_CALL(cudaGetLastError());
    CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    double * a = new double [length];
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(a,dev_a,byteSize,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (size_t index = 0; index < length; index++){
        printf("%.3f\n",a[index]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(dev_a));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceReset());
    delete[]a;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cudaMemchk?

Comment: `cuda-memcheck` reports numerous out-of-bounds shared memory writes. A brief look at the code suggests that this due to out-of-bounds pointer in `temp`.

Comment: @talonmies, @Park Young-Bae,i tried cuda-memcheck. Result are 48 errors like `Invalid __shared__ write of size 8`, 2 errors `Progam hit error 30 on CUDA API call to cudaDeviceSynchronize`, error `Program hit error 719 on CUDA API call to cudaModuleUnload`. I guess it happens because of asynchronous program execution: kernels starts, in spite of the fact that memory for `extern __shared__ double shrd[]` is not allocated. Also I'm very new in CUDA, so I can be wrong. Is there any ways to fix it? I mean to make kernel execution wait until memory for `extern __shared__ double shrd[]` is allocated?

Comment: @a.yuzhanin: The problem with the code are primarily the out-of-bounds memory accesses to shared memory. I would strongly suggest fixing that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on kepler or later first read this:
http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/

Otherwise if you are pre-kepler read this:
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf

There are some fundamentals you are missing in terms of CUDA programming. I have given you a template of your code below. It is for clarification of some of these fundamentals. Do not expect this to be optimized as I am expecting you to program the parallel reduction. This will get you started with an understanding on how to use shared memory.

Good Luck!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#define N 10000
#define K 100

#define CUDA_CALL(x) do { if((x) != cudaSuccess) { \
    printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__); \
    printf("%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(x)); \
    system("pause"); \
    return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0)

__global__ void kernel(double* a, double* results){

    extern __shared__ double shared[];

    size_t tid, tid_local, stride;
    tid       = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x; //thread id within all blocks
    tid_local = threadIdx.x;                      //thread id within a block
    stride    = blockDim.x*gridDim.x;             //total number of threads

    double *start = &a[K*blockIdx.x]; //each block will get K of a block.

    shared[tid_local]=start[tid_local]; //copy K elements into shared memory
    __syncthreads();

    //Perform Parallel reduction, you will have to implement this
    //After parallel reduction, result should be in shared[0]

    //for demonstration I made the code serial for each block on thread 0.
    //This is for demonstration only.
    double sum=0;
    if(tid_local==0){
        for(int i=0; i<K; i++){
            sum+=shared[i];
        }

        a[blockIdx.x]=sum;
    }

}

int main(){

    int devNum = 0;
    CUDA_CALL(cudaGetDevice(&devNum));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaSetDevice(devNum));


    double * dev_a = NULL;
    double * dev_results=NULL;

    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc(&dev_a, N*sizeof(double) ));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc(&dev_results, (N/K)*sizeof(double)));

    //copy dev_a onto GPU (this is the array you are summing).

    dim3 block_size(K,   1, 1);
    dim3 grid_size (N/K, 1, 1);

    size_t shmem_perBlock = K * sizeof(double);

    kernel <<< grid_size, block_size,  shmem_perBlock >>> (dev_a, dev_results);

    CUDA_CALL(cudaGetLastError());
    CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    //copy dev_results back to CPU, this is your result.

    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(dev_a));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(dev_results));

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```